# How i can patched deployment manifest

Tags: kubernetes, devops, kubernetes-helm, helm3

I try  to  run this command

```
kubectl patch deployment w-app-kuku-com -n stage -p '{"spec":{"template":{"spec":{"containers":[{"livenessProbe":{"successThreshold": "5"}}]}}}}'
```

And get this error

```
Error from server: map: map[livenessProbe:map[successThreshold:5]] does not contain declared merge key: name
```

I try  to  change livenessProbe or ReadnesProbe parameters for example successThreshold but cant !

Answer (score 1):

> successThreshold: Minimum consecutive successes for the probe to be
> considered successful after having failed. Defaults to 1. **Must be 1
> for liveness and startup Probes**. Minimum value is 1.

Asserted from [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#configure-probes), you can't patch `successThreshold` to other value beside setting it to 1 for `livenessProbe`.